# Requirements for qualified certificates in DIRECTIVE 1999/93/EC

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

DIRECTIVE 1999/93/EC at `ANNEX I Requirements for qualified certificates` states that one requirement for qualified certificates is

```
(a) an indication that the certificate is issued as a qualified certificate;
```

What is an example of this *indication*?

Could a qualified certificate fullfiling all the requirements in DIRECTIVE 1999/93/EC be provided? Maybe in PEM format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is provided for instance in [ETSI TS 101 862 "Qualified Certificate profile"](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101800_101899/101862/01.03.03_60/ts_101862v010303p.pdf):

> 5.3 Qualified Certificate Indication
>
> The following two techniques can be utilized to declare that a certificate is issued as a Qualified Certificate:
>
> 1) by identifying a certificate policy in the Certificate Policies extensions, as defined in clause 4.2.1.5 from 
>   RFC 3280 [3], clearly expressing that the issuer intentionally has issued the certificate as a Qualified 
>   Certificate and that the issuer claims compliance with annex I and annex II of the Directive [1]; or
>
> 2) by including a Qualified Certificate Statements extension with an esi4-qcStatement-1 statement as defined in 
>   clause 5.2.1 of this profile.

Note that each Member State can interpret 1999/93/EC as they want, so the "qualified" quality of a certificate does not really mean much (for instance Diginotar used to deliver qualified certificates in the Netherlands). For some examples of qualified certificates used by the European Commission, see [here](http://new.eur-lex.europa.eu/content/oj/e-oj/listing.html)

Comment: Just like `Comission Decision 2009/767/EC` says in ANNEX 2.2: `...there is no truly interoperable and cross-border profile for the QC...`

Comment: By the way, sad what happened to Diginotar...

Answer (score 1):

There are updated ETSI standards for Qualified Certificates.

EN 319 412-5 Qualified Certificate profile defines a profile for Qualified Certificates, based on the technical definitions of the IETF RFC3739, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3739.

TS 119 412-2 X.509 V3 Certificate Profile for Certificates
Issued to Natural Persons defines a common profile dependant on the IETF standards for implementation of X.509 V.3 and the ETSI standard TS 101 862 (EN 319 412-5), to allow actual interoperability of certificates.

These documents describe in detail what ETSI thinks are indications of a QC.